# Why isn't there hot water coming from my faucet after stem replacement?

Tags: plumbing

I just completed the replacement of the hot and cold water stems form my bathtub faucets. The hot water was leaking so I went ahead and replaced both. They were probably original to the house circa late 50's. After finally getting them loose I inserted new correct replacements. The problem now is that when I run the hot water I only get cold water. I let it run for several minutes but still had no hot water coming out. There is hot water everywhere else in the house, even the sink near the tub. Has any else ever heard of this or encountered this problem.

Comment: I know this is going to sound dumb but did you turn the hot water feed back on under the sink?  if you had water before did you have to wait for it to warm up?

Comment: Can you post some pics of your faucet and the stems you used, a lot of them have options for reversing them.

Comment: Did you bleed out the lines before hooking them back up or installed a cartridge back wards? If its a single handle, remove the cartridges and clean/replace them.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an older style (washer type) installation. Is it possible that part of an old washer is stuck in the seat, or was pushed back behind the seat into the pipe, preventing water flow? First, make sure you have hot water TO the tub area. Turn the water off and remove the hot side, stem and all. Inspect for obstructions. You may need to briefly turn the water back on with the stem OUT, to blow out any obstructions. Have a helper turn the water on and back off, as you watch for any debris coming out. Once you have established hot water to the valve, you can check for an obstruction AFTER the hot water valve where it feeds into the tub spout, either part of an old washer or other debris. With the valve stem out, and the cold water valve off, try blowing air back through the spout to clear this (it will go into the hot water valve area) and then clear the valve out again before replacing the stem and washer, handles, etc.

Nine times out of ten, some obstruction will be in the line either before the valve or after it, where it feeds into the common pipe to the spout.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single handle cartridge, remove and rotate it 180 degrees.  It worked for me.